# How to completely restart a flutter application on didChangeAppLifecycleState (iOS & android devices)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have an app that I want to completely restart when `AppLifeCycleState` is `.paused`

This appears to be working on `android (Pixel 3 XL Api 28)` but not for iOS devices.

### Native iOS Equivalent:

On my native iOS version of my app, I ran exit(0) in applicationDidEnterBackground function in AppDelegate.

I have tried making MyApp stateful with `WidgetBindingObserver` and listening for the changes to state. On .paused state I have tried to execute `exit(0)` and `SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod<void>('SystemNavigator.pop');`

Inside the state of MyApp

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        print('paused state');
        SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod<void>('SystemNavigator.pop');
        //I have also tried exit(0); here.
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        print('resumed state');
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        print('inactive state');
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.suspending:
        print('suspending state');
        break;
    }
  }
```

I expected that the app would exit and then on opening again would restart but it doesn't exit at all. It just resumes where it was before entering a paused state. This behaviour is only on iOS devices.

I understand that my code is not a fully working minimal example - please let me know if you need me to set up an example for people to try.

Comment: You can use 'restart_app' plugin. It can restart the whole app in OS level and it supports the iOS platform as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have resolved this issue but I'm not 100% sure why previous attempts to use `exit(0)` didn't work.

I have altered the `didChangeAppLifecycleState` function to the following.

```
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        print('paused state');
        SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod<void>('SystemNavigator.pop');
        if (Platform.isIOS) {
          exit(0);
        }
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        print('resumed state');
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        print('inactive state');
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.suspending:
        print('suspending state');
        break;
    }
  }
```

by adding the following code the app now exits on both android and iOS.

```
if (Platform.isIOS) {
          exit(0);
        }
```

If anyone can shed any light on why just using `exit(0)` by itself didn't work I would love to understand this better.